# Who was dreaming when and whose mind was being projected?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

Can someone provide an exhaustive list of

1. who was dreaming
2. whose mind was the one that filled it with its subconscious

in each dream they shared in [*Inception*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/)?

Comment: [Infographic](http://images.fastcompany.com/upload/InceptionArch_Slusher.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [*infographic*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reLi9.jpg) seems to explain everything you want in one concise picture

[image]

The following list is a summary of the image, with all the relevant dream levels and the persons in them (with the actual dreamer in bold, who is also the one that stays awake for the next level):

1. Van driving through the city:

   **Yusuf**, Arthur, Eames, Ariadne, Cobb, Fischer, Saito
2. Hotel:

   **Arthur**, Eames, Ariadne, Cobb, Fischer, Saito
3. Mountain fortress:

   **Eames**, Ariadne, Cobb, Fischer, Saito
4. Limbo ([whose mind was it, though?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/19931/49)):

   Ariadne, Fischer, Cobb, Saito (the last two for a bit longer)

Comment: Only now I see that this infographic is actually slightly wrong. It depicts *Saito* as if entering limbo some time before *Cobb* and *Ariadne*. But he actually entered it a little later, since he protected them for a short while in level 3 while they were searching for *Fisher* in limbo. In the same way *Ariadne* exited it a bit later than *Fisher*. But I guess such a level of accurateness hasn't been the purpose of this inforgraphic anyway.